# PHP foreach doesn't show the first array value

Tags: php

```
echo 'SSH Timeout: <select name="ssh_timeout"';
$time = array('1', '5', '15', '30', '60');

foreach ($time as $value) {
    if (15 == $value) {
        echo "<option value='$value' selected>$value seconds</option>";
    } 
    else {
        echo "<option value='$value'>$value seconds</option>";
    }
}

echo '</select>';
```

That code doesn't show the first value which is `1` but instead it starts from `5` to `60`. How do I fix it ?

Comment: Should work fine: https://3v4l.org/Z0Ipm can't reproduce it.

Comment: you should close the opening `<select...>` tag :)

Comment: @Dekel OMG, how could I not see that, how careless of me lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should close the opening `<select` tag, otherwise the `<option value='1'` gets inside the `<select` and the browser will not render it.

This is the fix:

```
echo 'SSH Timeout: <select name="ssh_timeout">';
$time = array('1','5','15','30','60');
    foreach ($time as $value) {
        if (15 == $value) {
            echo "<option value='$value' selected>$value seconds</option>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<option value='$value'>$value seconds</option>";
        }
    }
    echo '</select>';
```